problems with lower case table names
I just had to reinstall on my Mac the clean OS (monterey), installed a time machine backup and noticed that the mysql DB server 8.0.28 (oracle mysql community edition) would not start, or well it starts and shuts immediately down
Now after some digging, I saw in the error log something with lower_case_table_names, and edited the my.cnf correspondingly, strange thing is though that I get an error independent if I set lower_case_table_names to 0, 1 or 2
Is the issue with my file system? or what else can I do?
please note the last entry where I set it to 2, and then during startup it is set to 0 just to complain that it should be 2

lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system
'/usr/local/mysql/data/' is case sensitive.  Now setting
lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems.


Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').

lower_case_table_names = 0
myuser@Mac16 / % tail /usr/local/mysql/data/Mac16.local.err            
2024-05-30T01:44:18.516188Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-30T01:44:18.516324Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:44:18.542748Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-05-30T01:45:10.144861Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 20751
2024-05-30T01:45:10.157990Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-05-30T01:45:10.235253Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-05-30T01:45:10.240611Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').
2024-05-30T01:45:10.240753Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-30T01:45:10.240882Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:45:10.271434Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

lower_case_table_names = 1
myuser@Mac16 / % sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac16.local.pid).
myuser@Mac16 / % tail /usr/local/mysql/data/Mac16.local.err            
2024-05-30T01:45:10.240753Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-30T01:45:10.240882Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:45:10.271434Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-05-30T01:47:52.482477Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 21116
2024-05-30T01:47:52.495582Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-05-30T01:47:52.573040Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-05-30T01:47:52.578399Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('2').
2024-05-30T01:47:52.578557Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-30T01:47:52.578692Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:47:52.602172Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

lower_case_table_names = 2
myuser@Mac16 / % sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac16.local.pid).
myuser@Mac16 / % tail /usr/local/mysql/data/Mac16.local.err            
2024-05-30T01:47:52.578692Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:47:52.602172Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-05-30T01:48:05.888673Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 21252
2024-05-30T01:48:05.891839Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010160] [Server] lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system '/usr/local/mysql/data/' is case sensitive.  Now setting lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems.
2024-05-30T01:48:05.901830Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-05-30T01:48:05.978197Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-05-30T01:48:05.983490Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').
2024-05-30T01:48:05.983656Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-30T01:48:05.983795Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-30T01:48:06.007140Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.


and then during startup it is set to 0 - what is this precisely?

it has to do with the OS filesystem case sensitiveness apparently. But what mysql does is for me a mistery... It detects it is set to 2, even though FS is case sensitive, sets it to 0 to avoid future problems, and then complains that it is 0 and the data dictionary is 2.
My only solution insofar is to reinitialize the DB, but then I loose all the data within the DB.... I have a backup of the data folder, but a manually copying it into the new initialized DB did not help neither.

You can set the MySQL parameter lower_case_table_names when you are initializing the MySQL instance. Technically you can set lower_case_table_namesto either0,1or2`.
  Value   Meaning                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  0       Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name comparisons are case-sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or macOS). If you force this variable to 0 with --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result.  
  1       Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are not case-sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and table aliases.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2       Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case-sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case-sensitive! InnoDB table names and view names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.                                                                                                                          

After MySQL has been initialized you cannot change the value.
(emphasis mine)

lower_case_table_names can only be configured when initializing the server. Changing the lower_case_table_names setting after the server is initialized is prohibited.

Reference: 11.2.3 Identifier Case Sensitivity (MySQL Docs)
To change the value after you have created your MySQL instance you have to reinitialize/reinstall the MySQL instance.
